# Do I need joist hangers for deck frame on gravel pad? What is the nail size?

Tags: deck, joists

I am building 12'x14' detached deck in backyard and away from the house. Frame will be of pressure treated wood sitting on gravel pad. Essentially a rectangle build of 4x6 with one 4x6 in the middle and 8 2x6 joists spaced 16" OC.

Since I have solid support under the entire frame, do I still need joist hangers or is it ok to just use nails at the angle from inside (toe-nail)?

If so, what is recommended nail size? Ideally, I would like to use nail gun to quickly attach those joists.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need joist hangers.  Joist hangers are for use in spots where you're unable to put the nails directly through the frame into the joist already.

I built a shed with much the same construction, only my base frame sits on 2 6xx treated railroad ties embedded in the gravel bed, and I haven't had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using joist hangers with recommended #9 screws. That was pretty easy and gave me extra benefit of proper joist alignment so I didn't have to hold them in place.